# Slice a dataframe based on one column starting with the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, sql-like, string-matching

I have a dataframe called `data`, that looks like like this:

`|...|category|...|ngram|...|`

I need to slice this dataframe to instances where `category` starts with the value of `ngram`. So for example, if I had the following instance:

- category: beds
- ngram: bed

then that instance should be dropped from the resulting dataframe.

In T-SQL, I use the following query (which may not be the best way, but it works):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  category NOT LIKE ngram+'%';
```

I have read up on this a bit, and my best attempt is:

```
data[data.category.str.startswith(data.ngram.str) == True]
```

But this does not return any rows, nor does the inverse (using `== True`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#use df.apply to filter the rows with category starts with ngram.
data[data.apply(lambda x: x.category.startswith(x.ngram), axis=1)]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks works perfectly. The final code I used had some string conversion, and an inversion: `data[~(data.apply(lambda x: str(x.category).lower().startswith(str(x.ngram).lower()), axis = 1))]`